# How to unzoom Chrome-* console

Tags: google-chrome, console, zooming

I've a little problem with chromium 19.0.1058.0 (124615).
I've been in the console on the "new tab" tab. Then i wrote a function in the console, then i typed "}" (with <kbd>alt-gr</kbd>). It zoomed my console.

What can i do to reset the zoom in DevTools?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have the same problem when typing <kbd>]</kbd> with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> key the console interprets as `zoom in`.  ([More info on <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key))

To `zoom out` try pushing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

To type `}` try [its Ascii code, which is 125](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/curly-brackets-braces-closing-ascii-code-125.html):  <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>125</kbd>

Answer (score 68):

On Mac with a keyboard layout where you cannot do <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (since you need <kbd>shift</kbd> to do a <kbd>+</kbd>, like on the French keyboard layout) you  have to "**Undock into seperate window**", and only then can use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> like you would in a normal window.

Comment: This problem also affects Programmer Dvorak.

Comment: Hi on French layout (Ubuntu) `ctrl + 0` does the job.

Comment: Undock is the one for me, thank you.

Comment: Undocking into a seperate window was the solution to my problem! THANKS!

Answer (score 34):

**Reset chrome zoom to default inside console/devtools:**

**MAC version**: command(⌘) + 0

**WINDOWS version**: ctrl + 0

Type of keyboard might influence the result. In this case, just go to your machine's settings and set temporarily US keyboard.

Answer (score 20):

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts

[image]

1. Click inside the dev console, this puts it in focus.
2. Press the key combination specific to your operating system. 'Ctrl' & '-' to Zoom out on Windows/Linux

Comment: Thanks, but I got the answer looong ago ! Something like 5 years ago !

Comment: Still valuable for me! I thought I was getting old.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. shift with + or - zooms in and out on the page, but after clicking on the console only zooming out works. However cmd + 0 worked to restore the size to normal.

Comment: With my laptop french keyboard (lenovo yoga 700 14-isk) no minus is available ! only the dash key is.
Thus only "ctrl" + "0" allowed me to unzoom ...

Answer (score 15):

if that doesnt work, try clicking <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> and scroll with the mouse or touchpad scroller up or down to change zoom level

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well this unzoom the console too. So that's another answer.

Comment: @gung this does in fact answer the question, 1. The given answer did not help me, but my answer did 2. the author of the question agrees with me 3.

Comment: THIS THIS THIS THANK YOU SO MUCH WOULD YOU MARRY ME

Answer (score 13):

Updating the answer from the newest Chrome dev tools hotkey's documentation:

[image]

Found at: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts

Comment: I've mistakenly zoomed in my devtools panel and this `Ctrl` + `0` shortcut, takes it back to default zoom level. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9):

I am using brave (a chrome based browser). None of the shortcut above worked for me. To reset the zoom, I clicked on "Run command"

[image]

Then I searched for the "Reset zoom level" command.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, press `Ctrl + 0`. On Mac, press `Cmd + 0`.

Answer (score 4):

At least with my french keyboard, 
unlike documented within chrome, 
one should use

- ctrl+= 
  and
- ctrl+0

to zoom and unzoom

instead of ctrl++ ctrl+-

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the solutions suggested above didn't work for me.
To fix the issue, I had to (I am on a mac):

1. Close Chrome
2. Navigate to ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default
3. Open the Preferences file
4. Locate the `devtools`key and switch its zoom level to 0.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes on a japanese keyboard to zoom in you may need CMD + ^ instead

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this on Mac (tested on Mac 10.14.6 aka Mojave)
Go to System `Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Enable Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar`

[image]

This will show a new icon in the menu bar, open the Keyboard Viewer.
Now press CMD + 0 (on the number pad):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop (azerty keyboard) with my version of Chrome (with Ubuntu), only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>  seems to work to reset to default zoom (using the light-blue 0 associated with<kbd>, ?</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, if none work, try CTRL + 0 (or à)